# Cardinality of Borel sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

It seems it's well known that if a sigma algebra is generated by countably many sets, then the cardinality of it is either finite or $c$ (the cardinality of continuum). But it seems hard to prove it, and actually hard to find a proof of it. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the statement of your question. The $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,\infty)$ generated by all sets of the form $[0,n]$, $n\in\mathbb N$ is countable.\\You have mentioned Borel algebra in the title (but not in the body of you're question), so this is probably not what you want.

Comment: @Martin, that $\sigma$-algebra doesn't look countable to me.  Are you forgetting to close under complementation?

Comment: Thanks for the correction @ccc.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Let's say the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is generated by the sets $A_i \subseteq X$.  For each subset $I$ of the natural numbers, consider the set $B_I = \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i \cap \bigcap_{i \notin I} (X \setminus A_i)$.  For distinct sets $I$ and $J$, the corresponding sets $B_I$ and $B_J$ are disjoint.  Now take cases: either only finitely many of the $B_I$ are nonempty, or infinitely many are.  This will show that the $\sigma$-algebra is either finite or has cardinality at least that of the continuum.

To show that the $\sigma$-algebra cannot have cardinality strictly above that of the continuum is a bit more involved.  I can't come up with an approach avoiding transfinite induction up the Borel hierarchy.  Here's a sketch of what I have in mind:

We build an increasing family $S_\alpha$ of subsets of the power set of $X$, as $\alpha$ ranges over the countable ordinals.  In the end, $\bigcup_{\alpha < \omega_1} S_\alpha$ will be a $\sigma$-algebra of size at most continuum containing our countably many generators (in fact, it will be the $\sigma$-algebra they generate, but that's just an added bonus).  We start by setting $S_0$ to equal the (countable) set of generators.  Given $S_\alpha$, we let $S_{\alpha+1}$ be the collection of subsets which can be written as countable unions of the form $\bigcup_i A_i \cup \bigcup_j (X \setminus B_j)$, where $A_i$ and $B_j$ are chosen from $S_\alpha$.  Note that if $|S_\alpha| \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$, then $|S_{\alpha+1}| \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ as well (since there are only continuum many choices of ways to write the union: this is essentially the cardinal equality $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$).  For limit ordinals $\lambda$, let $S_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} S_\alpha$.  This will again satisfy $|S_\lambda| \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ provided each $S_\alpha$ in the union does.

Finally, we see $\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1} S_\alpha$ has cardinality at most that of the continuum, since $\aleph_1 \cdot 2^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.  Moreover, it is closed under the $\sigma$-algebra operations since any countable sequence of elements is accounted for in some $S_\alpha$ (with $\alpha < \omega_1$).

Comment: is there a good exposition on the transfinite induction proof?

Comment: I don't have the references on hand, but surely this appears in either Kechris' or Srivastava's text on descriptive set theory (possibly as an exercise).  In the meantime I will sketch the argument I have in mind in the answer.

Comment: Thanks! So it seems impossible to prove it without the axiom of choice?

Comment: Well certainly some amount of choice is required, since (modulo large cardinals) it's consistent with ZF that the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the reals is equinumerous with $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ (see, e.g., Gitik's model in which everything is singular).  I'm not sure whether, say, uncountable choice principles are really required, even though I tacitly used them in the sketch above.

Comment: @Xianghong, ccc: Arnold Miller wrote a paper about long Borel hierarchies without the axiom of choice. He shows that it is possible to have (without large cardinals) the length at $\omega_2$ or at any successor of a limit ordinal in $(\omega_1,\omega_2]$, all this while having $\omega_1$ singular. He goes on to suggest that under some large cardinal assumptions we can get even higher.

Comment: @Asaf: Really? But ccc pointed out above that it is consistent with ZF. What extra assumption does Miller make?

Comment: @Xianghong: For the hierarchy to be longer than $\omega_2$ you would need both $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ to be singular. This is approximately a Woodin cardinal in consistency strength.

Comment: @Xianghong: Also, Gitik model assumes ZF+a proper class of strongly compact cardinals.

Comment: When is induction done over *all* ordinals and when over countable ordinals only?

Comment: @MattN. 
When we want to prove something about ordinals, we usually use induction over ALL ordinals. On the other hand, when we are proving something about a particular set using transfinite induction (and transfinite recursion), we use the set of all ordinals small than a particular ordinal, say $\gamma$. In this answer, we need to choose $\gamma$ to be large enough to reach all Borel measurable sets, yet small enough so that we add at most continuum many new subsets only at most continuum many times.

Comment: We choose $\gamma$ to be the first uncountable ordinal because that's when $\cup_{\alpha < \gamma} S_\alpha$ becomes a sigma algebra, thereby reaching all Borel measurable subsets. This trick of choosing $\gamma$ to be an initial ordinal also appears in the construction of a subset of the plane crossing every line exactly twice, or other similar constructions.

Comment: As written, the argument in the first paragraph doesn't work. Take for instance $X=\mathbb N$, the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal P(X)$, and $A_n=\{n\}$. Then $B_I=\emptyset$ for all nonempty $I$, and no conclusion can be drawn.

Comment: @AsafKaragila May I ask where the axiom of choice is needed in the above proof? Thanks!

Comment: @Jiu: Numerous places. For example, $\aleph_1\cdot2^{\aleph_0}$ could be strictly larger than both; the cardinality of $\{A\subseteq\Bbb R\mid A\text{ is countable}\}$ could be larger than $2^{\aleph_0}$ which means that the argument about the cardinality of each "level" having size at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ also requires AC, and that the hierarchy stabilises at stage $\omega_1$ also requires that $\omega_1$ is a regular cardinal, which again requires a bit of AC.

Comment: Is it enough to define $S_{\alpha+1}$ as the set that contains all countable union and complement of elements from $S_{\alpha}$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila In the ending of the first paragraph, how does one know that if only finitely many of the $B_I$ are nonempty, then the σ-algebra is finite?

Answer (score 5):

It is easy to prove that the $\sigma$-algebra is either finite or has cardinality at least $2^{\aleph_0}$.
One way to prove that it has cardinality at most $2^{\aleph_0}$, without explicitly using transfinite recursion, is the following.
It is easy to see that it is enough to prove this upper bound for a "generic" $\sigma$-algebra, e.g., for the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$, or for the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of [the Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory)) $\mathcal{N} = \omega^{\omega}$.
Note that $\mathcal{N}$ is a [Polish space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space), so we can talk about [analytic subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set) of $\mathcal{N}$.
Every Borel subset is an analytic subset of $\mathcal{N}$ (in fact, $A \subseteq \mathcal{N}$ is Borel if and only if $A$ and $X \setminus A$ are both analytic).
So it is enough to prove that $\mathcal{N}$ has $2^{\aleph_0}$ analytic subsets.
Now use the theorem stating that every analytic subset of $\mathcal{N}$ is the projection of a closed subset of $\mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{N}$.
Since $\mathcal{N} \times \mathcal{N}$ has a countable basis of open subsets, it has $2^{\aleph_0}$ open subsets, so it has $2^{\aleph_0}$ closed subsets.
So $\mathcal{N}$ has $2^{\aleph_0}$ analytic subsets.

The proof using transfinite recursion might be simpler, but I think the analytic subset description gives a slightly different, kind of direct ("less transfinite") view on the Borel sets, that could be useful to know.