# non-Borel subset of uncountable Tychonoff space

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Let $X$ be an uncountable Tychonoff space. Must there exist a non-Borel subset of $X$?

Comment: By Borel set, do you mean a set which is in the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all the open sets?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it is the trivial counterexample, but take any uncountable discrete metric space. Every set is open, so every set is Borel.

Answer (score 0):

This is an addition to Asaf Karagila's correct answer.

The standard argument which works for $\mathbb{R}$ is like this: Let $\mathcal{O}(X)$ denote set of all open subsets of topological space $X$, $\mathcal{B}(X)$ set of all Borel subsets of $X$. Also let $σ(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{S})$ denote the $σ$-algebra generated by the system $\mathcal{A}$ in $σ$-algebra $\mathcal{S}$. So we have $\mathcal{B}(X) = σ(\mathcal{O}(X), \mathcal{P}(X))$.

Since generating a $σ$-algebra means adding countable unions and intersections, it holds that $|σ(\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{S})| ≤ $ <del>|A| + 2^ω</del> $|\mathcal{A}|^ω$. So if $X$ is a topological space such that $|\mathcal{O}(X)|^ω < |\mathcal{P}(X)|$, we have that $|\mathcal{B}(X)| ≤ |\mathcal{O}(X)|^ω < |\mathcal{P}(X)|$. So there is a non-Borel subset of $X$.

Also note that $|\mathcal{O}(X)| ≤ 2^{nw(X)}$, whete $nw(X)$ is network weight of a topological space $X$. So if $X$ satisfies $2^{nw(X)} ≤ |X|$, then we have $|\mathcal{O}(X)|^ω ≤ (2^{nw(X)})^ω = 2^{nw(X)} ≤ |X| < |\mathcal{P}(X)|$. So second countable space of size at least continuum (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$) has a non-Borel subset, as Tomek Kania says in his answer.

Comment: Your cardinal arithmetic doesn't take into consideration the case where the system $\cal A$ has a cardinal of countable cofinality (or cases where Singular Cardinal Hypothesis fails).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: You are right. I'll try to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes trivial counter-examples are very good and Asaf actually provided one. In general, as Asaf, pointed out the answer is **no**. However, it is a standard yet challenging exercise on transfinite induction to show that if your space $X$ is additionally second countable then [the cardinality of the family of Borel sets is continuum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70880/cardinality-of-borel-sigma-algebra). So the answer is **yes** for spaces which are second countable and have cardinality continuum.

Note that there are even compact Hausdorff spaces for which every subset is Borel – just take your favourite countable successor ordinal with the order topology. More generally, take any countable Tychonoff space.