# How to prove that the cardinality of the set of Borel sets is continuum?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the set of Borel sets on $R$, how to prove that $\overline{\overline{\mathscr{B}}}=\aleph$? That is ,  the cardinality of it is continuum?

Comment: Hint: What's the cardinality of the set of open sets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: We can prove it [this way](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70880/cardinality-of-borel-sigma-algebra), for example

Comment: Or, if you know that the cardinality of the open sets is $c$, find a way of indexing the borel sets by $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$

Comment: Hi. Omnomnomnom. Thanks for your answer. Yes. I can prove that the cardinality of the set of open sets of $R$ is $c$. Would you like to specific the way of indexing the borel sets by $R^N$? By the way, I do not like the transfinite induction.