# Existence of non-Borel subset

Tags: real-analysis

I got the following statement:

For each set $N \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ with cardinality of the continuum $\#N=\mathfrak c$ there is a subset $M \subseteq N$ with $M \notin \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$.

Can somebody tell me why this is true? I thought of different cardinalities, but that doesn't seem to work out.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cardinality of the Borel sigma algebra is the cardinality of the continuum (see [Cardinality of Borel sigma algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70880/cardinality-of-borel-sigma-algebra)).

The cardinality of the set of all subsets of $N$ is the cardinality of the power set of the continuum.

Hence?