# How many Borel sets are on an infinite Polish Space?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

I am learning Descriptive set theory, and my question is how many Borel sets are on an infinite Polish space?

I think they have the cardinality of the continuum, but I just do not see how to prove it.

Thanks

Comment: Poland cannot into space. (Slightly obscure reference)

Comment: @columbus8myhw: I've been to Poland once, and there were spacious areas there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cardinality of Borel sigma algebra](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70880/cardinality-of-borel-sigma-algebra)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Poland cannot into _outer_ space. (Inb4 Mirosław Hermaszewski — He's Ukrainian.)