# cardinality of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a second countable space

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, second-countable

Second countability by itself doesn't restrict the cardinality of a topological space, since every set with the trivial topology is a second countable space, but it seems natural to ask whether second countability restricts the cardinality of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the space.

Can the cardinality of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of a second countable space be arbitrarily big?
If this is the case is there a simple construction for a second countable space with an arbitrarily big Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: The answer of Eric Wofsey should be enough, if you're not familiar with ordinals a similar construction is a bit more detailed in Folland's Real analysis

Comment: @renart thanks for the reference!

Comment: @downvoter I'd like to know what was wrong with the question

Comment: @Renart, page/section in Folland? Thank you.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Do you have the precise reference to Folland?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

More generally, suppose $A$ is a collection of subsets of a set $X$ and let $B$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A$.  We can construct $B$ inductively as follows.  We define an increasing sequence $B_\alpha$ of collections of subsets of $X$, for each $\alpha<\omega_1$.  Let $B_0=A$, and given $B_\alpha$, let $B_{\alpha+1}$ be the set of complements, countable unions, and countable intersections of elements of $B_\alpha$.  If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, define $B_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} B_\beta$.  Then I claim that $$B=\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1} B_\alpha.$$  Indeed, clearly by induction $B_\alpha\subseteq B$ for all $\alpha$.  On the other hand, $\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1}B_\alpha$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, since given countably many elements of it they are all contained in some $B_\alpha$, and then their union and intersection (and the complement of any one of them) is contained in $B_{\alpha+1}$.  Since $B$ is by definition the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$, $B\subseteq\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1}B_\alpha$.

We can now use this to bound the cardinality of $B$.  Notice that $|B_1|\leq |A|^{\aleph_0}$ (assuming $|A|>1$).  Since $$(|A|^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=|A|^{\aleph_0^2}=|A|^{\aleph_0^2}=|A|^{\aleph_0},$$ it follows by induction that $|B_\alpha|\leq |A|^{\aleph_0}$ for all $\alpha$.  Thus $$|B|\leq \aleph_1\cdot |A|^{\aleph_0}=|A|^{\aleph_0}.$$

Finally, let us apply this to your question.  If $X$ is a second-countable space, we can take $A$ to be a countable basis.  Every open set is a countable union of elements of $A$ and is thus in $B$, so $B$ will be the Borel algebra of $X$.  We thus conclude that the Borel algebra has cardinality at most $$|A|^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}.$$  (Of course, this upper bound is easy to achieve, for instance for $X=\mathbb{R}$.)

Answer (score 2):

Second countable space $X$ has a countable base

$$\mathcal{B} = \{U_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$$

Since every open set $U$ is of the form

$$U = \bigcup\mathcal{B}^{'}\mbox{ where } \mathcal{B}^{'}\subseteq\mathcal{B}$$

then it is clear that $X$ has at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ open sets and thus at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ closed sets.

Let's consider three cases:

**1)** $X$ is $T_1$. Then every point is a closed set. In particular there are at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ points and since Borel $\sigma$-algebra is a subset of a power set, then the size of Borel $\sigma$-algebra is at most $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

**2)** $X/\sim$ is $T_1$ where

$$x\sim y\ \mbox{ if and only if }\ \bar{x}=\bar{y}$$

where on the right side we have closures. Consider a map

$$F:\mathcal{P}(Y)\to\mathcal{P}(X)$$
$$F(A) = \bigcup_{a\in A}a$$

Note that $A$ is a set of equivalence classes which are sets themselves and thus the definition makes sense. This function is "1-1" between closed sets and it obviously preserves countable unions and intersections. Thus it is "1-1" between Borel $\sigma$-algebras so it follows from **1)** $X$ has at most $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ Borel sets.

**3)** $X$ does not satisfy **2)**. TODO.

Comment: Your $Y$ is $T_0$, but not necessarily $T_1$.

Comment: Aha, you're right. So close. :/