# Is $C^\infty(U)$ a Borel subset of $L^2(U)$ when $U$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, borel-sets

OK, I was totally wrong in the last question : [Is a subspace of a separable Hilbert space always a Borel set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4684326/is-a-subspace-of-a-separable-hilbert-space-always-a-borel-set?noredirect=1#comment9907092_4684326)

Now, let me be more specific. Let $U$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and think of $L^2(U)$ with its inner product topology.  In this setting, $C^\infty(U)$ is clearly a vector subspace of  $L^2(U)$.

But, is $C^\infty(U)$ an element of the Borel $\sigma-$algebra generated by the inner product topology of $L^2(U)$?

This specific question seems to deserve a positive answer, I believe...but I still cannot find a rigorous justification. Could anyone help me?

Comment: How exactly do you define $C^\infty(U)$ for U compact?

Comment: OK, I was not specific enough. As a set, it is the union of all $C^\infty(U')$ where $U' \subset U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.