# Generated $\sigma$-algebras on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: measure-theory, definition, borel-sets

I’m reading up on $\sigma$-algebra generated by an arbitrary collection $\mathcal{C}$ of subsets of $\Omega$, which is defined as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ containing $\mathcal{C}$ and denoted $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$. The example I’m working with is $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, and $\mathcal{C}$ is the collection of open intervals. I’m having trouble seeing what kinds of subset of $\mathbb{R}$ would be in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$. Please let me know if the following makes sense:

- We have $\mathbb{R}, \emptyset \in \sigma(\mathcal{C})$ by definition of $\sigma$-algebra.
- Let $I_i = (a_i,b_i)$. Then $I_i \in \sigma(\mathcal{C})$, and also $I_i^c = (-\infty,a_i] \cup [b_i, +\infty) \in \sigma(\mathcal{C})$.
- $\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty}I_i = (a_1,b_1) \cup (a_2,b_2) \cup \dots \in \sigma(\mathcal{C})$.
- Taking the complement of the above also gives $(\bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty}I_i)^c = (-\infty,a_1] \cup [b_1,a_1] \cup [b_2,a_3] \cup \dots \cup [b_\infty,\infty) \in  \sigma(\mathcal{C})$ (I have doubts about the last semi-infinite interval, but I don’t know what else could happen here).

At this point it gets pretty complicated, and I suspect this might not be the way to go. Am I missing something here?

Also I need to show that $\sigma(\mathcal{C}) = \sigma(\mathcal{D})$, where $\mathcal{D}$ is the collection of semi-infinite intervals $\{(\infty,x]: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, but I’m not sure I should analyze $\sigma(\mathcal{D})$ in the same manner as above.

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think you'll be able to characterize all subsets of that sigma-algebra in a few bullet points. It will contain all nice sets (unions of closed intervals, open intervals, half open intervals, semi-infinite intervals, etc.), but there will be more that are hard to describe.
2. In general, to show $\sigma(\mathcal{C}) = \sigma(\mathcal{D})$, it suffices to show $\mathcal{D} \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{C})$
   and $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{D})$. (Do you see why?) Proving this amounts to constructing intervals of the form $(-\infty, x]$ by using operations on intervals of the form $(a_i, b_i)$, and vice versa.
3. A way to get a simple closed interval from your second bullet point: note that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty ((-\infty, a-1/n] \cup [b+1/n, \infty)) = (-\infty, a) \cup (b, \infty)$ and take the complement to get $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove that pretty much every set you can imagine is in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$. To find sets that are not in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is quite tricky, see [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).

However, keep in mind that the number of elements in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ has [the same cardinality as the set of real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70880/cardinality-of-borel-sigma-algebra) $\mathbb{R}$, so the sets which are not in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$

The construction of the Borel Set is in the first section of the [Borel set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) page of Wikipedia, but it uses transfinite induction, so it may be too much advanced for your current level.

Going back to your examples, you can prove that:

- finite unions and intersections are in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ (take $A_{n+1}=A_{n+2}=...=\emptyset$, respectively $\mathbb{R}$)
- singletons are in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ by writing $\{x\}=\bigcap_n(x-1/n,x+1/n)$
- infinite open intervals are in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ (for example $(a,\infty)=\bigcup_n(a,n)$
- closed and half-closed intervals are in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ (by attaching singletons at the ends of open intervals)
- open sets in standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ are in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ as countable unions of open intervals
- closed sets in standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ are in $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ as complements of open sets

and so on.